# check current time exists between model attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

From a model called `VehicleSchedule` with two `datetime` attributes `start_time` and `end_time`. How should I fetch number of vehicles scheduled in given time?

Something like bellow

```
VehicleSchedule.where('start_time >= ? and end_time <= ?', Time.current, Time.current).count
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation? As far as I can tell from your description, that works perfectly fine. The only *very minor* improvement would be to remove the duplication: `Vehicle.where('start_time >= :time and end_time <= :time', time: Time.current).count`

Comment: @TomLord `start_time: 17/10/2019 04:00` `end_time: 17/10/2019 05:00` and  for `current_time: 17/10/2019 04:30`  this is gonna fail rt?

Comment: Oh, wait... You have the `>=` and `<=` operators backwards. That's all.

Comment: BTW, your text says `VehicleSchedule` but the code uses `Vehicle`. Please fix that or – if there are actually two models – clarify how they are related to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You have the `<=` and `>=` operators backwards.

Also, you can remove duplication by referencing both values with the same placeholder:

```
Vehicle
  .joins(:vehicle_schedules)
  .where('vehicle_schedules.start_time <= :time AND vehicle_schedules.end_time >= :time', time: Time.current)
  .count
```